# Configuring VS code for c++ programming and development

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, configure

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\projects\helloworld\helloworld.cpp).C/C++(1696)
   cannot open source file "iostream"C/C++(1696)
```

The above is showing whenever I am trying to include or any other files. I have MinGw already installed and the path environments variables set already. I have also installed the c/c++ Microsoft extension in Vs code. Still I don't understand what is happening here.Can somebody help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

for (const string& word : msg)
{
    cout << word << " ";
}
cout << endl;
 }
```

This is the snippet I am trying to run.

Comment: Could you update your question with the exact `#include` code you're using? I see double quotes there, and that might be your issue.

Answer (score 1):

refer to this documentation.[documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)
set compiler path I think it will work

Comment: While the link might answer the question, it's better to include the revelant parts in the answer itself, as text. Otherwise, if the link dies, the answer will become useless. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure the Include path array setting in
`.vscode\c_cpp_properties.json`.

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Win32",
      "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**"],
      "defines": ["_DEBUG", "UNICODE", "_UNICODE"],
      "compilerPath": "C:\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "c11",
      "cppStandard": "c++17",
      "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x86"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

Source: [C/C++ for Visual Studio Code. Configurations.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_cc-configurations)
It can also help:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Comment: While the link might answer the question, it's better to include the revelant parts in the answer itself, as text. Otherwise, if the link dies, the answer will become useless. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers